# how to get data from two table having different no. of column

Tags: sql

i have two tables **table1** and **table2**. Table1  has only 1 row of data and 7 column.
for ex.
col1  col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7    having data such as 
(123 ,  abc  , dfg,  ed , " " ,  sc  , fgh)

table2 has 6 column .

i want to join these two table table on such a way that finla output should have 1st row having data of
table1 and from 2nd row data of 2nd table.
NO commom column is there between this two table
plz tell me how to write query for this.

Comment: No offense, but this is an LOL question. Use UNION.

Comment: union can't be use because there are differnt no. of columns

Comment: Hint - How do you get only the same number of columns for each table ? SELECT.

Comment: What's with this "1st row having data of table1 and from 2nd row data of 2nd table" ? If i understand your requirement correct, why don't you just pull in the data from the two tables into say, a view and do a select * on the view?

Comment: What are the column data types in the two tables? Please supply both table definitions.

Comment: @ Sayuri   . output of the query should be like this

Comment: Really @BoratSagdiyev? Everyone starts somewhere. StackOverflow has always been a very friendly site an I would like to keep it that way. From the OP you can judge English is not his first language and maybe he doesn't know the terms to search for. I agree its simple, but did you know of UNION until someone showed you or you read about it?

Comment: @EugeneNiemand - Okay, I LOL-ed because the op seems to have done no work. I should have asked him the google terms he used. Google "sql combine results", "sql add results of two queries" give the answer right away. Both look like basic english to me. Should have landed the OP on the right answer. Anyway, there should be a google tag so that people only ask how to google something. BTW, nice to see a person from UK. I love your great nation. Please see my tour of UK on youtube. Thank you my friend, I love you.

Comment: @y2j - dude. no offense. I did NOT give you the -1. Before asking questions, google them first if you have not done so already. If you don't speak english, then try to convert your language to english using `google translate`. Its not a perfect tool, but its free. Then, search google English. If you still can't find an answer, then ask a question on stackoverflow. Chenqui.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need them on 2 separate rows?
In that case, you can use the `UNION` as follows,

```
Select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7
from   table1 

UNION

Select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, ''
from   table2
```

That should return the two records in two different rows, with a null column for the table2 since it consists of one column less that table1.

***However, you have to ensure that the column types are similar in both tables for it to match!***

Comment: i can't use null because i need to generate a report output coming from the above query

Comment: using `union`, both table need to have same number of columns (of same types) and since you need them one after the other in same columns, you need to put a value for the column. You can replace the `NULL` by `''` though